# Bad Request when trying a simple Subscriber update using SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I am just starting with API and not even sure how to troubleshoot this. I am getting "Bad Request" after trying the following in POSTMAN. Went through similar posts, but didn't find an answer. Below is my request:

```
POST https://<<my SOAP Base URI>>.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
    <wsa:Action>Update</wsa:Action>
      <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com"><<---MY TOKEN--->></fueloauth>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
    <UpdateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Options>
            <SaveOptions>
               <SaveOption>
                  <PropertyName>*</PropertyName>
                  <SaveAction>UpdateOnly</SaveAction>
               </SaveOption>
            </SaveOptions>
         </Options>
         <Objects xsi:type="Subscriber">
            <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
            <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
            <EmailAddress>mynewemail@gmail.com</EmailAddress>
            <SubscriberKey>0031t00000BVbWMXX1</SubscriberKey>
         </Objects>
      </UpdateRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Try adding key: `SoapAction` and value: `Create` into the 'Headers' section in POSTman. Also make sure your Content-Type is `text/xml`

Comment: Thanks, this helped! I got the following response: <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus> but the email address didn't get updated, it's still showing the old value, any idea why?

Comment: OK figured it out - it should have been: key `SoapAction` and value `Update` - Thanks @Gortonington